# Cursor pointer not showing (CSS)

Tags: css

I have read the other threads but still could not figure this out. When I hover over a button with cursor:pointer; set it does not work. 
Not only that the hover effect does not work too.
I have posted all my code below, including the javascript. Not sure if it would have anything to do with the javascript or not, but I doubt it.

```js
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('.colorBtn');
const bodyBcg = document.querySelector('body');

const colors = [
  '#6C5B7B',
  '#C06C84',
  '#F67280',
  '#F8B195',
  '#EC2049',
  'A7226E',
  '45ADA8'
];

//add event listener

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', changeColor);

function changeColor() {
  // bodyBcg.style.backgroundColor = colors[2];

  //get random number, Math.floor gives you a number between 0 and 0.9999... so we round down and times by the length of the array
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  bodyBcg.style.backgroundColor = colors[random];
}
```

```css
body {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.colorBtn {
 padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
 border: 3px solid #fefefe;
 border-radius: 7px;
 color: #fefefe;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
}

.colorBtn:hover {
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="colorBtn">Press to change color</button>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'set it does not work'?

Comment: And the pointer is showing?

Comment: This is a css issue. If you look at the code I have set "cursor: pointer" and have added a hover effect. However when I hover over the "button" it does not change color and there is no pointer.

Comment: Which browser are you using? This code should work in chrome, edge and IE.

Comment: Chrome, that's strange

Comment: It randomly works now, that is the pointer is there, but the hover effect still does not work. I have not changed anything in the code so this is weird.

Comment: Did you `@include ` another php file? If yes, do you have another `.colorBtn` in the php file?

Comment: @ChengHuiYuan Fixed, I had two classes in my html in the tag and removed one and now it works. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two classes named `.colorBtn` in the css. Should work after removing the unnecessary one.

Comment: Thanks very much Cheng, I can't upvote yet as I don't have the privilege yet

Comment: Just as a comment. Everyone can up-vote. It is just that until you earn some rep, your votes are not displayed to everyone. But they are countered by the system and used in some metrics, AFAIU

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder why the color sometimes doesn't change, then add a line `console.log(random);` like the snippet below. Sometimes it seems to not change the color just because it did change but by randomly, it could change to the same color with the previous, so it looks like it doesn't work. But in fact, it works very well.

```js
const colorBtn = document.querySelector('.colorBtn');
const bodyBcg = document.querySelector('body');

const colors = [
  '#6C5B7B',
  '#C06C84',
  '#F67280',
  '#F8B195',
  '#EC2049',
  'A7226E',
  '45ADA8'
];

//add event listener

colorBtn.addEventListener('click', changeColor);

function changeColor() {

  // bodyBcg.style.backgroundColor = colors[2];

  //get random number, Math.floor gives you a number between 0 and 0.9999... so we round down and times by the length of the array
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  console.log(random);
  bodyBcg.style.backgroundColor = colors[random];
}
```

```css
body {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.colorBtn {
 padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
 border: 3px solid #fefefe;
 border-radius: 7px;
 color: #fefefe;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
}

.colorBtn:hover {
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="colorBtn">Press to change color</button>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```